# What is the benefit of boost intrusive pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137660/boost-intrusive-pointer) explains what an intrusive pointer in boost is. As far as I can see, an intrusive pointer is essentially the same as a shared pointer except the user must provide an interface for the reference counter by defining `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` functions.

Why would I want to manage reference count myself? What is the benefit of such approach?

Comment: My guess : to avoid having double reference counts if the object pointed to already has refcounting. (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html).
So it is a special case for optimization purposes, it even states : when in doubt just use std::shared_ptr

Comment: The boost manual mentions several [right in the intro](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. and follows that with the advice "As a general rule, if it isn’t obvious whether `intrusive_ptr` better fits your needs than `shared_ptr`, try a `shared_ptr`-based design first."

Comment: The boost documentation has a more detailed answer than should be expected from SO community